# Applying a function to a column, where the function's output is a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function wordInCell(word, listOfWords) that examines if any word within a given listOfWords is in a cell. The output of this function is a tuple, containing a boolean and a list of the words within the cell that are also contained within a list of words.

For example, if listOfWords = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse'], and a given cell in the DataFrame is 'The cat chased the mouse', this function would output (True, ['cat', 'mouse']).

I want to create two new columns that have each of these items. One column that indicates the truth value of whether any of the keywords within listOfWords is in a given cell. A second column that indicates what words if this is true.

Thus far I have tried:

```
df['Output'] = df['Text I want to examine'].apply(func=wordInCell, listOfWords = listOfWords)
```

As you would likely expect, this returned a new column called Output that contained a tuple in the form (bool, list) rather than one column indicating the boolean and one column indicating the list.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this dataframe:

```
  Text I want to examine
0                cat dog
1              dog mouse
```

Then you can apply `pd.Series` on your function:

```py
def wordInCell(word, listOfWords):
    out = [w for w in word.split() if w in listOfWords]
    return len(out) > 0, out

listOfWords = ['cat', 'dog']

df[['col1', 'col2']] = df['Text I want to examine'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(wordInCell(x, listOfWords = listOfWords)))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Text I want to examine  col1        col2
0                cat dog  True  [cat, dog]
1              dog mouse  True       [dog]
```